# R function parameter is "object not found"

Tags: r

I am passing in a csv file with two columns, the first being the major and the second being the courses in that major. For some reason when I run this, current_major is not showing up in my enviorment and when I run it in the console, it tells me that the object "current" is not found. I am having a lot of trouble understanding what is going wrong here.

```
course_data <- read.csv("file location")
majorCompare <- function(current, new){
  current_major <- which(course_data$major == current)
}
majorCompare("Animal Science", "American Studies")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is creating the object `current_major` within the scope of the function, and then it disappears into thin air when the function is finished. That's why you don't see it.

You *could* use the superassignment operator `<<-`

```
majorCompare <- function(current, new){
  current_major <<- which(course_data$major == current)
}

majorCompare("Animal Science", "American Studies")
```

But functions should ideally *return* something and not change your global environment. So do this instead.

```
majorCompare <- function(current, new){
   which(course_data$major == current)
}

current_major <- majorCompare("Animal Science", "American Studies")
```

You've also declared `new` as a function argument but it is never used within the function body.